# sonarqube-community-branch-plugin - pull request decorations are not working

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, sonarqube-scan, bitbucket-cloud

I am trying to make SonarQube 8.5 to work with BitBucket Cloud PR, so for AML settings I have used:

- BitBucket Server

  - **Bitbucket Server URL:** https://api.bitbucket.org/
  - **Personal Access token:** I have generated it `echo -n user:pass | base64`

In my `Project settings -> General Settings -> Pull Request Decoration`:

- **Project Key:** AN (the same from Project settings->Key)
- **Repository SLUG:** angularapp (from the URL)

**sonar-project.properties**

```
sonar.host.url=[SONAR_HOST]
sonar.login=[SONAR_TOKEN]
sonar.projectKey=test-app
sonar.projectName=My Test App
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=src
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
```

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
...
  pull-requests:
    "**":
      - step:
          name: SonarQube Analysis
          image: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli
          script:
            - sonar-scanner -X
              -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=$(pwd)
              -Dproject.settings=sonar-project.properties
              -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN
              -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=$BITBUCKET_PR_ID
              -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=$BITBUCKET_BRANCH
              -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=$BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH
...
```

I can see the PR in SonnarQube but there are no pull request decorations in my BitBucket Cloud PR, could you point me to what I am missing?

Also, in the `sonarqube_ce.log` I see that the report has been created but there is also an `HTTP Status Code: 404;` and I am not sure why

```
...
2021.01.18 11:57:53 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][c.g.m.s.p.c.p.b.c.BitbucketCloudClient] Create report on bitbucket cloud
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][c.g.m.s.p.c.p.b.c.BitbucketCloudClient] Create report: {"data":[{"title":"Reliability","value":"2 Bugs","type":"TEXT"},{"title":"Code coverage","value":0.0,"type":"PERCENTAGE"},{"title":"Security","value":"0 Vulnerabilities (and 0 Hotspots)","type":"TEXT"},{"title":"Duplication","value":0.0,"type":"PERCENTAGE"},{"title":"Maintainability","value":"0 Code Smells","type":"TEXT"},{"title":"Analysis details","value":{"text":"Go to SonarQube","href":"http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=test-app&pullRequest=4"},"type":"LINK"}],"details":"Quality Gate failed\n- C Reliability Rating on New Code (is worse than A)","title":"SonarQube","reporter":"SonarQube","link":"http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=test-app&pullRequest=4","result":"FAILED","created_on":"2021-01-18T11:57:45+0000","logo_url":"http://localhost:9000/static/communityBranchPlugin/common/icon.png","report_type":"COVERAGE","remote_link_enabled":true}
...
2021.01.18 11:57:53 ERROR ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.a.p.PostProjectAnalysisTasksExecutor] Execution of task class com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.ce.pullrequest.PullRequestPostAnalysisTask failed
com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.ce.pullrequest.bitbucket.client.BitbucketCloudException: HTTP Status Code: 404; Message:{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Resource not found"}}
...
```

```
2021.01.18 11:57:51 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.t.CeWorkerImpl] Execute task | project=test-app | type=REPORT | pullRequest=4 | id=AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz | submitter=admin
2021.01.18 11:57:51 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExtractReportStep] Analysis report is 89 KB uncompressed
2021.01.18 11:57:51 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Extract report | status=SUCCESS | time=11ms
2021.01.18 11:57:51 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist scanner context | status=SUCCESS | time=3ms
2021.01.18 11:57:51 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Propagate analysis warnings from scanner report | status=SUCCESS | time=1ms
2021.01.18 11:57:51 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Generate analysis UUID | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:51 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load analysis metadata | status=SUCCESS | time=9ms
2021.01.18 11:57:51 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Initialize | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:51 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Verify billing | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:51 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Build tree of components | components=3 | status=SUCCESS | time=6ms
2021.01.18 11:57:51 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Validate project | status=SUCCESS | time=3ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load quality profiles | status=SUCCESS | time=1046ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load Quality gate | status=SUCCESS | time=5ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load new code period | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.f.FileMoveDetectionStep] Either no files added or no files removed. Do nothing.
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Detect file moves | reportFiles=1 | dbFiles=1 | addedFiles=0 | status=SUCCESS | time=2ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load duplications | duplications=0 | status=SUCCESS | time=1ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.d.CrossProjectDuplicationStatusHolderImpl] Cross project duplication is disabled because it's disabled in the analysis report
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute cross project duplications | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute size measures | status=SUCCESS | time=1ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute new coverage | status=SUCCESS | time=1ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute coverage measures | status=SUCCESS | time=4ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute comment measures | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Copy custom measures | status=SUCCESS | time=2ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute duplication measures | status=SUCCESS | time=1ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute size measures on new code | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute language distribution | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute test measures | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute complexity measures | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load measure computers | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute Quality Profile status | status=SUCCESS | time=3ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   Execution time for each component visitor:
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - LoadComponentUuidsHavingOpenIssuesVisitor | time=2ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - IntegrateIssuesVisitor | time=31ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - CloseIssuesOnRemovedComponentsVisitor | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - MaintainabilityMeasuresVisitor | time=1ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - NewMaintainabilityMeasuresVisitor | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - ReliabilityAndSecurityRatingMeasuresVisitor | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - NewReliabilityAndSecurityRatingMeasuresVisitor | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - SecurityReviewMeasuresVisitor | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - NewSecurityReviewMeasuresVisitor | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - LastCommitVisitor | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.ExecuteVisitorsStep]   - MeasureComputersVisitor | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Execute component visitors | status=SUCCESS | time=40ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Checks executed after computation of measures | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute Quality Gate measures | status=SUCCESS | time=21ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute Quality profile measures | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Generate Quality profile events | status=SUCCESS | time=3ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Generate Quality gate events | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Check upgrade possibility for not analyzed code files. | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist components | status=SUCCESS | time=8ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist analysis | status=SUCCESS | time=1ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist analysis properties | status=SUCCESS | time=4ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist measures | inserts=51 | status=SUCCESS | time=15ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist live measures | insertsOrUpdates=201 | status=SUCCESS | time=61ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist duplication data | insertsOrUpdates=0 | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist new ad hoc Rules | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist issues | cacheSize=0 bytes | inserts=0 | updates=0 | merged=0 | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist project links | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist events | status=SUCCESS | time=5ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist sources | status=SUCCESS | time=5ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist cross project duplications | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Enable analysis | status=SUCCESS | time=1ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Update last usage date of quality profiles | status=SUCCESS | time=6ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.p.p.KeepOneFilter] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2020-12-21 and 2021-01-17
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.p.p.DefaultPeriodCleaner] <- Delete analyses of component AXcU5YSwOqP4NZDhT2Pw: 
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.p.p.KeepOneFilter] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2020-01-20 and 2020-12-21
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.p.p.DefaultPeriodCleaner] <- Delete analyses of component AXcU5YSwOqP4NZDhT2Pw: 
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.p.p.KeepOneFilter] -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2016-01-25 and 2020-01-20
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.p.p.DefaultPeriodCleaner] <- Delete analyses of component AXcU5YSwOqP4NZDhT2Pw: 
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.p.p.KeepWithVersionFilter] -> Keep analyses with a version prior to 2019-01-21
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.p.p.DefaultPeriodCleaner] <- Delete analyses of component AXcU5YSwOqP4NZDhT2Pw: 
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.p.p.DeleteAllFilter] -> Delete data prior to: 2016-01-25
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.p.p.DefaultPeriodCleaner] <- Delete analyses of component AXcU5YSwOqP4NZDhT2Pw: 
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.d.purge.PurgeDao] <- Delete aborted builds
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Purge db | status=SUCCESS | time=36ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.IndexAnalysisStep] Call org.sonar.server.measure.index.ProjectMeasuresIndexer@344ff45d
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.IndexAnalysisStep] Call org.sonar.server.component.index.ComponentIndexer@1c771776
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.s.IndexAnalysisStep] Call org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexer@492281bb
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Index analysis | status=SUCCESS | time=136ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Update need issue sync for branch | status=SUCCESS | time=3ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Send issue notifications | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Publish task results | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Trigger refresh of Portfolios and Applications | status=SUCCESS | time=0ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.a.p.PostProjectAnalysisTasksExecutor] Webhooks | globalWebhooks=0 | projectWebhooks=0 | status=SUCCESS | time=3ms
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][c.g.m.s.p.c.p.PullRequestPostAnalysisTask] found 4 pull request decorators
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][c.g.m.s.p.c.p.PullRequestPostAnalysisTask] using pull request decorator bitbucket
2021.01.18 11:57:52 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][c.g.m.s.p.c.p.b.c.BitbucketCloudClient] Deleting existing reports on bitbucket cloud
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> CONNECTION 505249202a20485454502f322e300d0a0d0a534d0d0a0d0a
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000000     6 SETTINGS      
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE 
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000003   182 HEADERS       END_HEADERS
2021.01.18 11:57:52 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000003     0 DATA          END_STREAM
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000000    36 SETTINGS      
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE 
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000003   371 HEADERS       END_HEADERS
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000003    61 DATA          
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000003     4 RST_STREAM    
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000003     0 DATA          END_STREAM
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000003     4 RST_STREAM    
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000003     4 RST_STREAM    
2021.01.18 11:57:53 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][c.g.m.s.p.c.p.b.c.BitbucketCloudClient] Create report on bitbucket cloud
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][c.g.m.s.p.c.p.b.c.BitbucketCloudClient] Create report: {"data":[{"title":"Reliability","value":"2 Bugs","type":"TEXT"},{"title":"Code coverage","value":0.0,"type":"PERCENTAGE"},{"title":"Security","value":"0 Vulnerabilities (and 0 Hotspots)","type":"TEXT"},{"title":"Duplication","value":0.0,"type":"PERCENTAGE"},{"title":"Maintainability","value":"0 Code Smells","type":"TEXT"},{"title":"Analysis details","value":{"text":"Go to SonarQube","href":"http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=test-app&pullRequest=4"},"type":"LINK"}],"details":"Quality Gate failed\n- C Reliability Rating on New Code (is worse than A)","title":"SonarQube","reporter":"SonarQube","link":"http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=test-app&pullRequest=4","result":"FAILED","created_on":"2021-01-18T11:57:45+0000","logo_url":"http://localhost:9000/static/communityBranchPlugin/common/icon.png","report_type":"COVERAGE","remote_link_enabled":true}
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> CONNECTION 505249202a20485454502f322e300d0a0d0a534d0d0a0d0a
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000000     6 SETTINGS      
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE 
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000003   205 HEADERS       END_HEADERS
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000003   856 DATA          END_STREAM
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000000    36 SETTINGS      
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE 
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE 
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000003   371 HEADERS       END_HEADERS
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000003    61 DATA          
2021.01.18 11:57:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] << 0x00000003     0 DATA          END_STREAM
2021.01.18 11:57:53 ERROR ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.a.p.PostProjectAnalysisTasksExecutor] Execution of task class com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.ce.pullrequest.PullRequestPostAnalysisTask failed
com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.ce.pullrequest.bitbucket.client.BitbucketCloudException: HTTP Status Code: 404; Message:{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Resource not found"}}
    at com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.ce.pullrequest.bitbucket.client.BitbucketCloudClient.validate(BitbucketCloudClient.java:188)
    at com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.ce.pullrequest.bitbucket.client.BitbucketCloudClient.uploadReport(BitbucketCloudClient.java:139)
    at com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.ce.pullrequest.bitbucket.BitbucketPullRequestDecorator.decorateQualityGateStatus(BitbucketPullRequestDecorator.java:94)
    at com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.ce.pullrequest.PullRequestPostAnalysisTask.finished(PullRequestPostAnalysisTask.java:160)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.api.posttask.PostProjectAnalysisTasksExecutor.executeTask(PostProjectAnalysisTasksExecutor.java:118)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.api.posttask.PostProjectAnalysisTasksExecutor.finished(PostProjectAnalysisTasksExecutor.java:109)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeListener(ComputationStepExecutor.java:91)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:63)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:81)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$ExecuteTask.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:235)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$ExecuteTask.run(CeWorkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.findAndProcessTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:162)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$TrackRunningState.get(CeWorkerImpl.java:137)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:89)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021.01.18 11:57:53 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.p.a.p.PostProjectAnalysisTasksExecutor] Pull Request Decoration | status=FAILED | time=1068ms
2021.01.18 11:57:53 INFO  ce[AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz][o.s.c.t.CeWorkerImpl] Executed task | project=test-app | type=REPORT | pullRequest=4 | id=AXcVW8FkOqP4NZDhT2Pz | submitter=admin | status=SUCCESS | time=2625ms
2021.01.18 11:59:53 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000000     8 GOAWAY        
2021.01.18 11:59:56 DEBUG ce[][o.i.http2.Http2] >> 0x00000000     8 GOAWAY
```

Comment: Is there not a stacktrace with that last error log?

Comment: @mc1arke I added the whole extended version of the log

Comment: Can you try setting the URL for your sonarqube instance in the administration pages: `Server Base URL` setting (`sonar.core.serverBaseURL` property)? Bitbucket cloud doesn't accept localhost in report URLs to prevent any sort of phishing or XSS attack.

Comment: No effect, the same error appears again, by the way, I am using `ngrok` as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Are there any warnings in the sonarqube project ? You can view the warnings in SonarQube UI for the partuclar project. If there are warnings, could you please paste the same here.

Comment: @SouravAtta no there any errors or warnings

Comment: @IvayloCherkezov did you manage to solve it?